# How do old questions get "modified today" but show no new changes in the SO top questions list?

Tags: discussion, support

Today on Stack Overflow I clicked a question tagged in my watch-list [Shell - Delete line if the line has only one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69451656/3422102) and looked at it:

- The question has value, is clear and relevant.
- The question has answers (2) and one is selected as answering the question.

So, there were no problems with the question, the answers were correct, and in about as concise form as is possible. Then I looked at *"Why is this question here?"* and looked at the date: Oct 5, 2021.

I checked for edits and new comments - something that would provide any reason I could think of that this question would be back in the top-questions list - no new comments and no edits since Oct 5, 2021.

Then looking closely under the title in a very small font there is the indication "Modified today". Clicking on the link does nothing and there is nothing dated in the question to show what changed.

How am I supposed to tell what changed if there are no updated dates for the question, answers or comments?

Should clicking the "Modified today" link show me something? The question seems to reload, but no new information is displayed.

Or is this something we just chalk up to new AI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question had been closed on Oct 5, 2021 and has been reopened today as can be seen in the [timeline of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69451656/timeline). The timeline can be accessed by clicking on the clock icon below the voting arrow, or by appending `/timeline` to the link of the post (`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/[question-id]/timeline`).

Comment: Thank you -- that is the piece I was missing. Okay, I have to change `"questions"` to `"posts"` in the link and then append `/timeline` in place of the title. (I'll select this as answering when the timeout expires)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or you just click the link to go to the post's timeline page. The post's timeline is linked with a clock-like icon under the post's "saves" button, which is under the post's voting buttons and score display, which are all to the left of the post content.

Comment: Ahah! That's where it is hidden. I rarely have a need to look at timelines, and this was one case where I would. This was just a chance case I that I got to the question through the top-questions list -- it has already cycled off again. Thanks again for pointing me to the link.

Comment: Aside from the technique mentioned there: many things can cause such a bump. Some are intentionally done by the Community user to draw attention to old inactive questions that don't meet criteria for automatic deletion. It can also happen if an answer is added and then deleted. I agree that the interface is confusing, and the "clicking the link just refreshes the page" aspect is really obnoxious.